# Image keyboard : selecting rich content(Gif, Stickers) reopens activity

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, gboard

I am trying to implement image keyboard support in my app. I followed [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/image-keyboard). To support this I needed to override `EditText`'s `onCreateInputConnection` to tell softkeyboard what app is supporting & a callback to get the selected content Uri.

**EditText :**

```
override fun onCreateInputConnection(editorInfo: EditorInfo): InputConnection {
    val ic: InputConnection = super.onCreateInputConnection(editorInfo)
    EditorInfoCompat.setContentMimeTypes(editorInfo, arrayOf("image/jpeg", "image/png"))

    val callback =
        InputConnectionCompat.OnCommitContentListener { inputContentInfo, flags, opts ->
            val lacksPermission = (flags and
                    InputConnectionCompat.INPUT_CONTENT_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION) != 0
            // read and display inputContentInfo asynchronously
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1 && lacksPermission) {
                try {
                    inputContentInfo.requestPermission()
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    return@OnCommitContentListener false // return false if failed
                }
            }

            // read and display inputContentInfo asynchronously.
            // call inputContentInfo.releasePermission() as needed.

            true  // return true if succeeded
        }
    return InputConnectionCompat.createWrapper(ic, editorInfo, callback)
}
```

**its working fine. Surprise!!!**

***problem*** is when I added intent filter to a activity. After adding intent filter callback `InputConnectionCompat.OnCommitContentListener` doesn't called anymore & it opens activity with supported intent filter.

**Manifest :**

```
<activity
            android:name=".Main2Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main2">

        <intent-filter> <-- this filter is added
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

            <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

sample is available in [github](https://github.com/sayem405/MyApplication)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why & how, but changing from

```
EditorInfoCompat.setContentMimeTypes(editorInfo, arrayOf("image/jpeg", "image/png"))
```

**to**

```
EditorInfoCompat.setContentMimeTypes(editorInfo, arrayOf("image/*"))
```

solved the problem

Comment: It was passing the wrong mime type for the editorInfo. It was set to be jpeg or png while the selected images where gifs/stickers. Now any kind of image can be selected.